# Docusign PHP add multipule signature tabs

Tags: docusignapi

I'm currently trying to add multiple signature tabs same signer. I can only ever get one to appear on the pdf.

Code gets single signature

```
$signHere = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();
$signHere->setXPosition("100");
$signHere->setYPosition("100");
$signHere->setDocumentId("1");
$signHere->setPageNumber("2");
$signHere->setRecipientId("1");

// add the signature tab to the envelope's list of tabs
$tabs = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
$tabs->setSignHereTabs(array($signHere));
```

Tried

```
// add the signature tab to the envelope's list of tabs
$tabs = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
$tabs->setSignHereTabs(array($signHere));
$signHere3 = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([ # DocuSign SignHere field/tab
    'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1', 'recipient_id' => '1', 
    'tab_label' => 'SignHereTab', 'x_position' => '195', 'y_position' => '147'
]);
$tabs->setSignHereTabs(array($signHere3));
$signHere4 = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([ # DocuSign SignHere field/tab
    'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '2', 'recipient_id' => '1', 
    'tab_label' => 'SignHereTab1', 'x_position' => '195', 'y_position' => '147'
]);
$tabs->setSignHereTabs(array($signHere4));


// add a signer to the envelope
$signer = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer();
$signer->setEmail($recipientEmail);
$signer->setName($recipientName);
$signer->setRecipientId("1");
$signer->setTabs($tabs);
```

Also tried

```
$signHere = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();
$signHere->setXPosition("100");
$signHere->setYPosition("100");
$signHere->setDocumentId("1");
$signHere->setPageNumber("2");
$signHere->setRecipientId("1");

$signHere2 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();
$signHere2->setXPosition("200");
$signHere2->setYPosition("200");
$signHere2->setDocumentId("1");
$signHere2->setPageNumber("2");
$signHere2->setRecipientId("1");


// add the signature tab to the envelope's list of tabs
$tabs = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
$tabs->setSignHereTabs(array($signHere));

$tabs = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
$tabs->setSignHereTabs(array($signHere2));
```

I need three signature tabs on page two of my uploaded PDF.

I have also tried Anchor tags. Didn't replace the text string.

Any help Please?

Answer (score 0):

Your $tabs array is getting overwritten/cleared each time you execute this line:

```
 $tabs = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
```

You should create as many tab objects as you need, then add them all to a single array of tabs, and then assign that to the signer.